# Loading data into text fields via jQuery/AJAX/JSON

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have this page that has a variable number of text fields, each named `item_####` where `####` is the ID of the item the text field is representing. I would like to auto-populate these fields with how much of the item is in stock after the user clicks a button. The JSON return wouls look like this:
  `[#### : 45], [#### : 62]`
(note the lack of `item_` in the key)

I'm having trouble working my head around how I can load that data into multiple text fields based on the returned results of a php script. I would assume a loop would be in order, however I'm extremely new to Javascript and jQuery, so I'm lost when it comes to loading this content dynamically...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data format is not clear, but you could do something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Simple JSON</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="generator" content="Geany 0.20" />
    <script type="text/Javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/Javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.13/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/Javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('[name="button"]').click(function(){
                $.get('json.php',function(data){
                    data = $.parseJSON(data);
                    $.each(data,function(i,v){                      
                        $('[name="item-'+i+'"]').attr('value',v);
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <input name="text-1" />
    <input name="text-4" />
    <input name="button" type="button" value="update" />
</body>

</html>
```